# onActivityResult in Zxing

Tags: android, android-activity, zxing

I integrate Zxing library to my project, i have:
1. `MainActivity` with button , which start `CaptureActivity` 
2. SecondActivity with textView.
I need to put result code of `CaptureActivity` to the textView of `SecondActivity`, i put some code to `onActivityResult` of `CaptureActivity`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  if (requestCode == HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE) {
      Intent intent1=new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent1);


    int itemNumber = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.History.ITEM_NUMBER, -1);
    if (itemNumber >= 0) {
      HistoryItem historyItem = historyManager.buildHistoryItem(itemNumber);
      decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, historyItem.getResult());
    }
  }
}
```

but nothing happened, where im wrong? i read a lot on stackoverflow, but cant understand

My MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public void onCapture(View view) {
    Intent data=new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);

    startActivity(data);
}
```

}

from method onCapture i start CaptureActivity of Zxing  ,

SecondActivity :

`public class SecondActivity  extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }
}`

Comment: Could you add the entire code? And explain a bit more..

Comment: i have main activity:

Comment: Do you mean onActivityResult never gets called? If so can you post the code that calls CaptureActivity please.

Comment: i call **CaptureActivity** from **startActivity** , its ok , i cant call SecondActivity from **CaptureActivity** when i scanned QR/Barcode

Answer (score 1):

You launch the activity like this:

```
public void onCapture(View view) {
    Intent data=new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);

    startActivity(data);
}
```

But you need to use startActivityForResult

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

You will also need to move your onActivityResult code into MainActivity, so the flow will be

MainActivity -> CaptureActivity -> MainActivity -> Launch Second Activity

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use puteextra to send data from one activity to an other.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);   
String s = "whatever";
i.putExtra("YOU_NAME_IT", s);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in SecondActivity you will have to get that string.

```
Extras extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getString("YOU_NAME_IT");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know this but i dont understand where i must put this code, to CaptureActivity? Where i must put this?